# mysql2 gem doesn't work with rake test:(units|functionals|etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Task not supported by 'mysql2'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@project/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/databases.rake:380
```

Here is the code around the arrea where the error occured:

```
desc "Empty the test database"
task :purge => :environment do
  abcs = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
  case abcs["test"]["adapter"]
  when "mysql"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.recreate_database(abcs["test"]["database"], abcs["test"])
  when "postgresql"
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
    drop_database(abcs['test'])
    create_database(abcs['test'])
  when "sqlite","sqlite3"
    dbfile = abcs["test"]["database"] || abcs["test"]["dbfile"]
    File.delete(dbfile) if File.exist?(dbfile)
  when "sqlserver"
    dropfkscript = "#{abcs["test"]["host"]}.#{abcs["test"]["database"]}.DP1".gsub(/\\/,'-')
    `osql -E -S #{abcs["test"]["host"]} -d #{abcs["test"]["database"]} -i db\\#{dropfkscript}`
    `osql -E -S #{abcs["test"]["host"]} -d #{abcs["test"]["database"]} -i db\\#{RAILS_ENV}_structure.sql`
  when "oci", "oracle"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.structure_drop.split(";\n\n").each do |ddl|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(ddl)
    end
  when "firebird"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.recreate_database!
  else
    raise "Task not supported by '#{abcs["test"]["adapter"]}'"
  end
end
```

line 380, is the `raise` line at the end.

Everything started working when I added this to `mysql` case:

```
  when "mysql", "mysql2"
```

Is there a newer version of rails that has this fixed? ( < 3.0?)? I don't want to have to tell everyone to add `,"mysql2"` when the want to run tests. =\

Or is this a bug in rails 2.3.x?

I'm using rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 2.3.10 may fix it per this issue: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/83